# Website - Load Data Intensive Content After the Entire Page Loads

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, web

I'll get right into it. What I have is a div that takes a while to load because it involves calling API's and indexing content. The div itself takes much longer to load when compared to the rest of the page. What I would like to do is load the entire page, and then once the data is fetched, it loads the div on its own. Maybe put like a loading animation in place while this happens. I'm just wondering what the best way would be to accomplish this.

I'm not sure if this is relevant for this question but I am using Google App Engine in the Python environment.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start fetching the data after the DOM loads.

```
<html>

    <body>
    </body>

    //load data here !

</html>
```

Alternatively you can use jQuery DOM Ready event to load your data after the DOM elements have loaded:

```
<html>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // DOM is loaded, get data here
            });
        </script>

        <body>
        </body>


    </html>
```